# Minimizing a file path

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple program that "minimizes" a file path. Minimizing simply means replacing unnecessary file entries with entries that mean the same thing:

- `path1/path2/../path3` is replaced with `path1/path3`
- `path1/./path2` is replaced with `path1/path2`

I've achieved this using regex and it seems to cover all cases, but it also feels very slow and I have a hunch it might be prone to infinite loops:

```
private static final Pattern ONE_DOT = Pattern.compile("/\\./");
private static final Pattern TWO_DOTS = Pattern.compile("[^/]+/\\.\\./?");

public static String minimize(final String in) {
    String tmp = in;
    while (!stringIsMinimized(tmp)) {
        tmp = ONE_DOT.matcher(tmp).replaceAll("/");
        tmp = TWO_DOTS.matcher(tmp).replaceAll("");
    }
    return tmp;
}

public static boolean stringIsMinimized(final String str) {
    return !(ONE_DOT.matcher(str).find() || TWO_DOTS.matcher(str).find());
}
```

Comment: `"path1/..../path2/"` yields `"../path2/"`

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually doesn't work, because you use `replaceAll`. This means that your pattern will allow you to match `../../` and replace it with , resulting in a lost double-back. You can fix this two ways:

1. You could change the `replaceAll` to `replaceFirst`
2. You could change the pattern to exclude `../../` (`[^/.]+/\\.\\./?` works)

You can then simplify your loop since the `ONE_DOT` case will be matched properly so you don't need to split out a check for minimization.

Thus I would suggest:

```java
private static final Pattern ONE_DOT = Pattern.compile("/\\./");
private static final Pattern TWO_DOTS = Pattern.compile("([^/.]+/\\.\\.)+/?");

public static String minimize(final String in) {
    String tmp = in;

    tmp = ONE_DOT.matcher(tmp).replaceAll("/");

    while (TWO_DOTS.matcher(tmp).matches())
        tmp = TWO_DOTS.matcher(tmp).replaceAll("");

    return tmp;
}
```

At least as a first-pass improvement. There may be a way to do it without the loop using some kind of counting regular expression, but off the top of my head I'm not sure.

Comment: The fastest solution would probably be an iterator, a stack and some look-around.

Comment: Yeah, fastest would probably be something like `Arrays.stream(in.split("/")).filter(x -> !x.equals(".")).reduce("", {some lambda here})`

Answer (score 1):

> Your code looks great!

Here, maybe another option that we might exercise would be to possibly do the entire task with an expression, maybe something similar to these:

```
^(.+?\/).+\/(.+)$
(.+?\/).+\/(.+)
```

Our first capturing group is non-greedy, collects our desired `path1` for both inputs, followed by a greedy `.+` that'd continue upto the last slash, and our `path2` and `path3` are in this group: `(.+)`, and our desired output can be called using `\1\2`.

*Escaping might be unnecessary, just following based on the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZfVoB/1/)*.

---

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(.+?\\/).+\\/(.+)$";
final String string = "path1/path2/../path3\n"
     + "path1/./path2";
final String subst = "$1$2";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println(result);
```

#### Demo

```
console.log(`path1/path2/../path3
path1/./path2`.replace(/^(.+?\/).+\/(.+)$/gm, `$1$2`));
```

#### Performance

```
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
    const regex = '/^(.+?/).+/(.+)$/gm';
    const str = `path1/path2/../path3`;
    const subst = `$1$2`;

    var match = str.replace(regex, subst);
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]